# SOpt em App para Android e outras plataformas

Tags: suporte, android-app

Alguém sabe se tem alguma previsão de lançamento de um App para android do SOpt assim como existe para o SOen? ou ainda se tem algum projeto em desenvolvimento, pois seria muito interessante, pois poderíamos acompanhar as notificações pelo app e acessar o site quanto tivesse alguma atualização de nosso interesse ou mesmo usar nele o bate papo.

Comment: Post similar: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1681/stack-remote-no-windows

Answer (score 5):

O App já disponível para [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin) e [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stack-exchange/id871299723?mt=8) não é só do SO, funciona com todos os sites da rede, incluindo o SOpt. O único porém é que não há suporte a chat.

Comment: Estava procurando o StackOverflow, não tinha visto esse, não funciona no meu aparelho, mas valeu a dica.

Comment: Esse que eu linkei é o único oficial.

Comment: Como filtra as perguntas do SOpt no aplicativo? Pra mim só aparece as do SOen.

Comment: Pelo menu do app você pode escolher qualquer site da rede,  @RodolphoSa

Comment: Não achei essa opção no menu. Poderia colocar um print?

Comment: Achei no aplicativo Stack Exchange. No aplicativo Stack Overflow realmente não tem essa opção.

Answer (score 2):

O *app* não funciona no meu aparelho, mas o site na versão *mobile* (tirando um ou outro *bug*) funciona muito bem, inclusive o *chat*.

Comment: +1 concordo plenamente, até tive a testar e preferi a versão mobile.