# Por quê o app do StackExchange não é divulgado no site?

Tags: suporte, android-app

Perdoe-me a ignorância, mas não encontrei em nenhum lugar do site, um link para download do aplicativo mobile do StackExchange. Eu sei que o app existe na [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin), como visto [nesta resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1696/6226) mas não compreendo o porquê do app não ser divulgado.

Comment: Ok, encontrei o [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin) [nesta pergunta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1695/sopt-em-app-para-android-e-outras-plataformas). Mas continuo achando que deveria ser exposto de forma mais visível no site.

Comment: Avelino tens o aplicativo na [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin&hl=pt_PT)

Comment: Verdade Avelino, creio que o app deveria ser mais promovido. Quando o encontrei foi por curiosidade e não porque o site me sugeria.

Comment: Editei, por que "não existe" app para SOpt ou SOen especificamente, o que existe é um app para SE que acessa qualquer comunidade do mesmo (só não tenho certeza se acessa as comunidades "private beta")

Answer (score 8):

O aplicativo do Stack Exchange está nas respectivas lojas:

### [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin)

## [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stack-exchange/id871299723)

Comment: Existe algum motivo para ele não ser divulgado no site? O app é ótimo, estou me dando muito bem com ele.

Comment: @Avelino Que bom! Mas não sei porque a gente não divulga mais...

Comment: @Gabe com um certo nível de pontos as propagandas diminuem? Ou estou enganado?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento De que forma a pontuação interfere na propaganda? Você diz a pontuação na Google Play Store?

Comment: Não @Avelino, talvez não apareça mais no seu caso, mas na lateral direita as comunidades StackExchange mostram uma propaganda, mas notei que conforme seus pontos sobem em uma comunidade as propagandas diminuem, note que eu posso estar totalmente enganado.

Comment: Windows Phone mandou lembranças.

Comment: @re22 é menos de 2% dos acessos

Comment: @re22 além de mudares sempre de nome ainda usas Windows Phone? Devias ser proibido de usar tecnologia :P

Comment: @JorgeB. Eu gosto de viver a vida perigosamente

Comment: Sdds Windows Store

Answer (score 6):

*Eu não sei se está é a resposta mais correta, é apenas uma suposição.*

Eles divulgam o aplicativo desde que você acesse de um aparelho mobile, do qual eles tenham suporte, por exemplo, se acessado o SOpt de um iPhone eu terei isto no rodapé:

[image: Download app]

Em outra palavras, não tem por que divulgar o aplicativo para iOS ou Android em Desktops, já que acessando pelo Desktop não tem como detectar a tecnologia do SmartPhone do usuário (se é que ele tem um).

Porém no momento que acessar uma comunidade SE pelo navegador do Android ou iPhone irá aparecer uma "propaganda" discreta no rodapé, como demonstrado na imagem anterior.

### Se a pergunta fosse: Por que a divulgação do APP é tão discreta?

Devo presumir que o motivo seja porque os aplicativos não tem suporte completo ainda, não tem "fila de analise", "ferramentas para moderadores" e ainda estão sujeitos a mais bugs do que a versão "web", em outras palavras, acredito que este seja o motivo.

### Nota:

1. Eu conheci o APP ao acessar o SE, não me lembro se foi o *meta.stackexchange.com* o o *blog.stackexchange.com*, eu não tenho certeza, mas acredito que conforme os seus pontos aumentem as propagandas (que agora só ficam do lado direito das comunidades) diminuam conforme a pontuação e também pode haver a possibilidade de ter propaganda "direcionada", ou seja você já tem o aplicativo, não tem porque divulgar novamente para ti.
2. Não tem muita propaganda no SOpt, mas no SOen costuma aparecer sobre o carreiras e também uma propaganda divulgando o SOpt, que me faz acreditar que estas propagandas sejam mesmo "direcionadas".

Comment: Ficaria feliz se tivesse o chat dentro da versão mobile. :)

Comment: @gmsantos Você, todos os usuários e principalmente todos os funcionários :D

Comment: É mesmo é a única coisa que falta...